# how can I control my cpu frequency form a kde widget

Tags: kubuntu, kde, cpu, plasma, frequency

I noticed on the distro on the PineBook it has a widget to control cpu frequency is their a way to do this on a intel CPU on kde to save battery

Comment: Modern Intel processors should be using the intel_pstate CPU frequency driver by default. Test by `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`. The maximum CPU frequency for that driver can be set via, using 70% as an example: `echo 70 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct`. I am a server person and don't even know what a "widget" is.

Comment: Correction: the intel_cpufreq CPU frequency scaling governor (A.K.A. intel_pstate in passive mode) can also have the max CPU frequency set via the same command. Note that the one location sets the max for all CPUs.